# Powershell Send-MailMessage foreach different values in csv

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach

To all,

I have a csv where every row has a contractors samaccount, its account expiration date, the contractor's supervisor name and respective email address.

I have the following data in my csv:

```
Name,AccountExpirationDate,Submitter,SubmitterEmail
Username1,9/21/2019,Submitter1,Submitter1@b.com
Username2,9/22/2019,Submitter2,Submitter2@b.com
Username3,9/23/2019,Submitter3,Submitter3@b.com
```

When I execute the code below, it does send an email for each row but the message only states username3 data in each email. How can I correct this so that submitter1@b.com receives username1 data, likewise for submitter2 receiving username2 data, etc?

```
$from    =  "Your Friends in IT <a@b.c>"
$subject =  "Your contractors's login account will expire soon!"
$body    =  "Hello <br>"
$body    +=  "Your contractor's login account for <b>$Name</b></font> is set to expire on<b> $AccountExpirationDate</b>.<br>"
$body    +=  "Kind Regards,<br><br>"
$body    +=  "Your friends in IT"       
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\ps\SAC-Accounts-ExpiringSoon.csv"
$csv | foreach {
  $Name = $_.name
  $to = $_.SACSubmitterEmail
  $_.AccountExpirationDate = $_.AccountExpirationDate -as [datetime]
  $_
      }
ForEach ($user in $csv)
{
$mail = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Mailmessage $from, $to, $subject, $body
$mail.IsBodyHTML=$true
$server = "mail.b.com"
# $port   = 25
$Smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SMTPClient $server,$port
$Smtp.Credentials = [system.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
$smtp.send($mail)
}
```

Comment: `$csv | foreach {}` is not needed if you already have a foreach loop after it that iterates over the same data. Combining your efforts into one loop will probably fix most of the problems. Since you aren't doing anything with the `foreach-object` except setting variables, when you reach the next loop you only have the last values set by the previous `foreach-object`. Your intention appears to be to loop twice but simultaneously, but it doesn't have that effect.

Comment: Also, you have a few issues with variable names: `$_.SACSubmitterEmail` is not mentioned in the script or CSV columns. You might fix the stated problem by changing this line: `$mail = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Mailmessage $from, $to, $subject, $body`   to   `$mail = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Mailmessage $from, $user.SubmitterEmail, $subject, $body`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of the issue is having one loop that sets variables required by the next loop on ***every iteration of the first loop***, but the next loop never gets them until the first loop completes. In this example, it is best to just combine both loops' efforts into a single loop. You can use `Foreach-Object` or `foreach`.

```
$from    =  "Your Friends in IT <a@b.c>"
$subject =  "Your contractors's login account will expire soon!"      
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\ps\SAC-Accounts-ExpiringSoon.csv"

ForEach ($user in $csv)
{
    $Name = $user.Name
    $to = $user.SubmitterEmail
    $AccountExpirationDate = $user.AccountExpirationDate -as [datetime]
    $body =  "Hello <br>"
    $body +=  "Your contractor's login account for <b>$Name</b></font> is set to expire on<b> $AccountExpirationDate</b>.<br>"
    $body +=  "Kind Regards,<br><br>"
    $body +=  "Your friends in IT"

    $mail = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Mailmessage $from, $to, $subject, $body
    $mail.IsBodyHTML=$true
    $server = "mail.b.com"
    # $port   = 25
    $Smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SMTPClient $server,$port
    $Smtp.Credentials = [system.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
    $smtp.send($mail)
}
```

PowerShell will not read ahead in your code and determine what a variable value is. It must be assigned and defined before PowerShell needs to retrieve the value. Based on how your code was constructed, `$body` was expecting `$name` and `$AccountExpirationDate` to be already be assigned.

Comment: That makes too much sense! Thank you so much.